# With desired capabilities is deprecated in Selenium 4, how to automate Windows desktop application using Winium in Python 3?

Tags: python, selenium, winium

The following code no longer works in Python Selenium 4 since "desired capabilities" is deprecated.

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='http://localhost:9999',
    desired_capabilities={
        "app": r"C:\Windows\System32\control.exe",
        "platformName": "Windows", "deviceName": "WindowsPC"
    })
```

I'm seeing below error when I run it.

C:\Learning\Pytest\PytestBasics\Test.py:23: DeprecationWarning: desired_capabilities has been deprecated, please pass in an Options object with options kwarg
driver = webdriver.Remote(
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Stacktrace:
at Winium.Desktop.Driver.CommandExecutors.NewSessionExecutor.DoImpl()
at Winium.Desktop.Driver.CommandExecutors.CommandExecutorBase.Do()

How shall I make this work? I understand, in Java, I can use DesktopOptions class, but how to do it in Python?
I'm stuck at the moment & didn't find any answers over the internet. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Have you found any solution? I have similar problem when trying to use Selenium 4